# Convert image obtained from url into inputstream. Then read that inputstream to convert it into image & display on my jsp

Tags: java

```
package imageByte;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;

public class ImageByte {

    // private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ImageByte.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        getImageAndTypeFromInputStream();

    }

    public static byte[] getImageAndTypeFromInputStream() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        String format = null;
        BufferedImage bufferedimage = null;
        InputStream input = null;

        URLConnection openConnection = new URL("http://www.thumbprintbooks.ca/wp-content/uploads/Vignettes-Photos-Spine-Inset-In-Plinth-thumbnail-c-Thumbprint-Books.jpg").openConnection();
        openConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36");

        input = openConnection.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("input : " + input.toString());
        System.out.println("input : " + input.getClass());
        System.out.println("input : " + input.available());


        ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(input);
        System.out.println("iis : " + iis.toString());
        System.out.println("iis : " + iis.getClass());
        System.out.println("iis : " + iis.readBoolean());
        System.out.println("iis : " + iis.length());

        Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
        System.out.println("readers : " + readers.toString());
        System.out.println("readers : " + readers.getClass());

        if (readers.hasNext()) {

            System.out.println("if block");
            ImageReader reader = readers.next();
            format = reader.getFormatName();
            reader.setInput(iis);
            bufferedimage = reader.read(0);

            new BufferedImageWrapper(format, bufferedimage);

            final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bufferedimage, "jpg", byteArrayOutputStream);
            return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        } else {
            System.out.println("else block");
            String text = "OOPS !!!";
            byte convertEntry[] = text.getBytes();
            return convertEntry;
        }

    }

    public static class BufferedImageWrapper {

        private final String imageType;
        private final BufferedImage bufferedimage;

        public BufferedImageWrapper(String imageType, BufferedImage bufferedimage) {
            System.out.println("in Buffered image Wrapper");
            this.imageType = imageType;
            this.bufferedimage = bufferedimage;
        }

        public String getImageType() {

            return imageType;
        }

        public BufferedImage getBufferedimage() {

            return bufferedimage;
        }

    }
}
```

OUTPUT :

input : sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@3e3abc88

input : class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream

input : 14195

iis : javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageInputStream@300ffa5d

iis : class javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageInputStream

iis : true

iis : -1

readers : javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator@433c675d

readers : class javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator

else block

Comment: ..please explain your problem.

Comment: Please provide the relevant samples and highlight where your problem is and what it is

Comment: @Al1 I am retrieving an image from the URl then converting it into an inputstream which is then transformed into an ImageInputStream. Imagereader is used to read this imageInputStream and stored in the variable bufferedimage. Then this buffered image, its format and a new byteArrayOutputStream is passed to the ImageIO.write   Then byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray() is to be used to display the image

Comment: @idiotduffer please refer the above comment

Comment: The control is going in the else block instead of 'if block', which should not happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will solve your problem.

```
package com.intellectdesign.cash.gdm.common;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;

public class ImageByte {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        getImageAndTypeFromInputStream();

    }

    public static byte[] getImageAndTypeFromInputStream() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        String format = null;
        BufferedImage bufferedimage = null;
        InputStream input = null;

        URLConnection openConnection = new URL("http://www.thumbprintbooks.ca/wp-content/uploads/Vignettes-Photos-Spine-Inset-In-Plinth-thumbnail-c-Thumbprint-Books.jpg").openConnection();
        openConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36");

        input = openConnection.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("input : " + input.toString());
        System.out.println("input : " + input.getClass());
        System.out.println("input : " + input.available());

        BufferedInputStream in=new BufferedInputStream(input);

        ImageInputStream stream=ImageIO.createImageInputStream(in);

        Iterator readers=ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);

        if (readers.hasNext()) {

            System.out.println("if block");
            ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) readers.next();
            format = reader.getFormatName();
            reader.setInput(stream);
            bufferedimage = reader.read(0);

            new BufferedImageWrapper(format, bufferedimage);

            final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bufferedimage, "jpg", byteArrayOutputStream);
            return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        } else {
            System.out.println("else block");
            String text = "OOPS !!!";
            byte convertEntry[] = text.getBytes();
            return convertEntry;
        }

    }

    public static class BufferedImageWrapper {

        private final String imageType;
        private final BufferedImage bufferedimage;

        public BufferedImageWrapper(String imageType, BufferedImage bufferedimage) {
            System.out.println("in Buffered image Wrapper");
            this.imageType = imageType;
            this.bufferedimage = bufferedimage;
        }

        public String getImageType() {

            return imageType;
        }

        public BufferedImage getBufferedimage() {

            return bufferedimage;
        }

    }
}
```